# How can we identify whether a transaction contains attachements in corda

Tags: corda

How can we identify whether a transaction contains attachment.

if there is an attachment how can we retrieve the hash id from the transaction

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 4.0 (Kotlin) you can do

```
val tx = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(signedTx.id)
```

To access a transaction's attachment hash.

If you want to get the actual attachment, you should be able to do

```
tx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub)
```

To convert `tx` from a `validatedTransaction` to a `LedgerTransaction` (that should allow you to access the list of attachments).